# Why does $\left| {\det A} \right| \le \prod\limits_{j = 1}^n {(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left| {{a_{ij}}} \right|} )} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant

Let $A \in {M_n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $A = \left[ {{a_{ij}}} \right]$.

Why does $\left| {\det A} \right| \le \prod\limits_{j = 1}^n {(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left| {{a_{ij}}} \right|} )} $ is true?

Comment: What is *your* definition of $\det A$?

Comment: @ Quang Hoang - Determinan of matrix $A$

Comment: I understand it is the determinant. I'm asking what is the determinant of a matrix $A$?

Comment: @QuangHoang I find your question confusing. Are there substantially distinct definitions of the determinant, in the sense that the values for some matrix differ? I believe what you actually want to know is what properties of det OP is willing to admit. Which of them is "the definintion" seems tangential.

Comment: @quid You are right. Maybe next time I should simply ask the OP for the context. However, there are several *definitions*, i.e. different approaches, of $\det$. I did teach a course where $\det$ was defined as a magic function with all the properties. And if OP were anything like my students, it might be painful explaining why $\det$ is that horrifying sum.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $$\det A=\sum_{(i_1\cdots i_n)}(-1)^{\text{sgn}(i_1\cdots i_n)}a_{1i_1}\cdots a_{ni_n}.$$
Hence, $$|\det A|\le\sum_{(i_1\cdots i_n)}|a_{1i_1}|\cdots |a_{ni_n}|.$$
Verify that $$\prod\limits_{j = 1}^n {(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left| {{a_{ij}}} \right|} )}\ge\sum_{(i_1\cdots i_n)}|a_{1i_1}|\cdots |a_{ni_n}|$$ and complete the proof. (Note that there are $n^n$ terms on the left while $n!$ terms on the right.)

Comment: @user1551 Yes, thanks for pointing out the mistake.